# Are these ideals the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I have already proved that $(X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X)\subseteq(X^2-Y,X-Y^2)$ since the elements $X^3-Y^3$ and $X^2Y-X $ can be written as a linear combination of $(X^2-Y,X-Y^2)$.

However, I can't write $X^2-Y,X-Y^2$ as a combination of $(X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X)$. How can I prove that $(X^2-Y,X-Y^2) \subseteq(X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X)$ or they are not the same ideals?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X^2-Y,X-Y^2) \subseteq(X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X)$, then $X^2-Y\in (X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X)$. There exist two polynomials $f,g$ such that $X^2-Y=(X^3-Y^3)f(X,Y)+(X^2Y-X)g(X,Y)$. Send $X$ to $0$ in the equation and find $Y=Y^3f(0,Y)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $1=Y^2f(0,Y)$. Now send $Y$ to $0$ and obtain $1=0$, a contradiction.

Conclusion: $(X^3-Y^3,X^2Y-X)\subsetneq(X^2-Y,X-Y^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I = (X^3 - Y^3, X^2 Y - X)$ and $J=(X^2-Y,X-Y^2)$.  As you have pointed out, we have $I\subset J$.

Let $K=(X^2,XY,Y^2)$, and let $I' = I +K$, and $J' = J+K$.  Since $I=J\implies I'=J'$, it is enough for us to show that $I' \neq J'$.

$K$ is exactly the set of all polynomials of degree $\geq 2$.  In particular, $X^3,Y^3, X^2 Y, X^2$, and $Y^2$ all lie in $K$.  So we calculate: $I' = (X) + K$ and $J'=(X,Y) + K$.

But then $Y\in J'$, but $Y\notin I'$, and we conclude that $I'\neq J'$, which is what we wanted.

(A more refined version of this argument will tell you a little more about which elements in $J$ do not lie in $I$.)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand anything. Could you give a further explanation?

Comment: @Blanca I've reworked the solution to use only elementary facts about ideals.  Let me know if there's any step you'd like elaboration on.